# How to make the pygame.display.update () method keep displaying the window?

Tags: python, pygame

I made a game of Reversi using the pygame module. This script works, but there is a small problem. The effect I want to achieve is to display the results of this move after the player has moved, pause for a period of time (for example, 2 seconds), and then display the computer moves and results. But after running my script, the computer's moves and results are displayed immediately after the player’s move. I tried time.sleep () but it didn't work. After testing, I found the cause of the problem. Pygame.display.update () can only display one frame of screen. If there is no event loop, the screen cannot be displayed continuously. How to solve this problem?
I am a beginner in programming and know that the code I write is not smooth and efficient. Here is my code. I think the problem lies in the last few lines of code.

```
import pygame, os, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

def initBoardList():
    boardList = []       
    for x in range(8):
        boardList.append([])
        for y in range(8):
            boardList[x].append(' ')        
    boardList[3][3] = 'X'
    boardList[3][4] = 'O'
    boardList[4][3] = 'O'
    boardList[4][4] = 'X'
    return boardList

def move(boardList, coordinate, symbol):
    if isValidMove(boardList, coordinate, symbol):
        x = coordinate[0] - 1
        y = coordinate[1] - 1
        boardList[x][y] = symbol
        flipableTiles = detectaAll(boardList, coordinate, symbol)
        flipTile(boardList, flipableTiles)        

def drawBoard(boardList, boardSurface, tileColour1, tileColour2):
    for x in range(8):
        for  y in range(8):
            if boardList[x][y] == 'O':
                pygame.draw.circle(boardSurface, tileColour1, (80 * x + 120, 80 * y + 120), 30, 0)
            if boardList[x][y] == 'X':
                pygame.draw.circle(boardSurface, tileColour2, (80 * x + 120, 80 * y + 120), 30, 0)

def isFree(boardList, coodinate):
    x = coodinate[0] - 1
    y = coodinate[1] - 1
    return boardList[x][y] == ' '

def isFull(boardList):
    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(8):
            if boardList[x][y] == ' ':
                return False
    return True

def flipTile(boardList, flipableTiles):
    for coordinate in flipableTiles:
        x = coordinate[0] - 1
        y = coordinate[1] - 1
        if boardList[x][y] == 'X':
            boardList[x][y] = 'O'
        elif boardList[x][y] == 'O':
            boardList[x][y] = 'X'

def reverseTile(symbol):
    if symbol == 'O':
        return 'X'
    if symbol == 'X':
        return 'O'

def detectOnedirection(boardList, coordinate, symbol, delta):
    flipableTiles = []
    deltaX = delta[0]
    deltaY = delta[1]
    x = coordinate[0] -1
    y = coordinate[1] -1    
    while True:        
        x += deltaX
        y += deltaY
        if x < 0 or x > 7 or y < 0 or y > 7 or boardList[x][y] == ' ':
            return []        
        elif boardList[x][y] == reverseTile(symbol):
            flipableTiles.append((x+1, y+1))  
        elif boardList[x][y] == symbol:
            return flipableTiles      



def detectaAll(boardList, coordinate, symbol):
    deltas = [(0, 1),(0, -1),(1, 1),(1, -1),(1, 0),(-1, 0),(-1, 1),(-1, -1)]
    flipableTiles = []
    for delta in deltas:
        flipableTiles += detectOnedirection(boardList, coordinate, symbol, delta)
    return flipableTiles

def getComputerMove(boardList,symbol):
    bestMove = None
    highestScore = 0
    cMoveable = moveable(boardList, symbol)
    for coordinate in cMoveable:
        if coordinate in [(1,1),(1,8),(8,1),(8,8)]:
            return coordinate
        else:
            score = len(detectaAll(boardList, coordinate, symbol))
            if score > highestScore:
                bestMove = coordinate
                highestScore = score
    return bestMove 


def isValidMove(boardList, coordinate, symbol):
    x = coordinate[0] -1
    y = coordinate[1] -1  
    return 0 < coordinate[0] < 9 and 0 < coordinate[1] < 9 and \
        isFree(boardList, coordinate) and len(detectaAll(boardList, coordinate, symbol)) != 0

def countScore(boardList, symbol):
    score = 0
    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(8):
            if boardList[x][y] == symbol:
                score += 1
    return score

def moveable(boardList, symbol):
    moveable = []
    for y in range(1,9):
        for x in range(1,9):
            if detectaAll(boardList, (x, y), symbol) != [] and isFree(boardList, (x,y)):
                moveable.append((x, y))
    random.shuffle(moveable)
    return moveable  



boardList = initBoardList()
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
turn = 'player'
pygame.init()
boardSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800), 0, 32)
boardSurface.fill(blue)
pygame.display.set_caption('Reversi')
for i in range(9):
        pygame.draw.line(boardSurface, black, (80, 80 + 80*i), (720, 80 + 80*i), 2)
        pygame.draw.line(boardSurface, black, (80 + 80*i, 80), (80 + 80*i, 720), 2)


drawBoard(boardList, boardSurface, black, white)                
pygame.display.update()
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if  event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            os._exit(1)
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                os._exit(1)

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and turn == 'player':
            x = (event.pos[0] - 80)// 80 + 1
            y = (event.pos[1] - 80)// 80 + 1
            if isValidMove(boardList, (x, y), 'O'):                
                move(boardList, (x, y), 'O')       
                turn = 'computer'  
    drawBoard(boardList, boardSurface, black, white)                
    pygame.display.update()    


    if turn == 'computer':    
        cm = getComputerMove(boardList, 'X')
        move(boardList, cm, 'X')            
        turn = 'player'  
        drawBoard(boardList, boardSurface, black, white)      
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: My python and pygame versions are 3.7.6 and 1.9.6.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read how to ask good questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the minimal verifiable concrete example. Not many professionals to wade through unnecessary chunks of code.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put time.sleep() originally?
I placed it here:

```
    if turn == 'computer':    
        cm = getComputerMove(boardList, 'X')
        move(boardList, cm, 'X')            
        turn = 'player'  
        drawBoard(boardList, boardSurface, black, white)
        time.sleep(2)
        pygame.display.update()
```

and it works fine. The computer no longer immediately plays after you.

Comment: It doesn't work. Although the computer will wait 2 seconds before moving, the result can only be displayed once per round. The goal I want to achieve is to display two results in turn each time: the result after the player moves and the computer after the move.